# Rotation Matrix which maps a point to an specific point

Tags: matrices, geometry, vectors

How can I compute the rotation matrix which rotates an $n$-dimensional vector $\vec{A}$ around an $n-D$ vector $\vec{O}$, and maps it to a vector $\vec{B}$
(while $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{O}$ are known)?

Comment: What do you mean by rotating an $n$-dimensional vector around an $n-D$ (dimensional?) vector? The three-dimensional notion of "rotating around a vector" doesn't generalise to higher dimensions. What generalises is the notion of "rotating in a plane". Do you mean that $\vec O$ is to be the centre of rotation? If so, what does it mean that it has $n-D$ dimensions? And is $\vec B$ at the same distance from $\vec O$ as $\vec A$?